# PATH not a recognised environ variable but clearly exists

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, anaconda

[image: screenshot]

How is this behaviour explained?

```
import os
print os.environ.keys()
```

is listing `PATH` amongst its keys, however:

```
import os
print os.environ["PATH"]
```

gives the error:

`NameError: name 'PATH' is not defined`

Furthermore, the above code works fine once written within a python environment.

As seen, I have defined a PATH environment variable for both the user and the system (via control panel).

OS is Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you had was you were printing `["PATH"]` in a line that was already surrounded with "import ... "

This isn't a Python problem, it's a shell problem (in this case, CMD.exe from windows). The `"import` double quote starts a string. The string continues until it sees a double quote - right before PATH. So you wind up with

```
  quoted string: import os; print os.environ[
unquoted string: PATH
  quoted string: ]
```

Which all gets glued together to produce:

```
import os; print os.environ[PATH]
```

Notice, no quotes around PATH? Python sees that, and looks for a symbol PATH, which isn't defined. So it prints an error.

As @Tomasz Kajtoch points out, you can solve this by either "escaping" the quotes you use, or switching flavors of quote:

```
python -c "import os; print os.environ[\"PATH\"]"
```

**or**

```
python -c "import os; print os.eniron['PATH']"
```

Comment: Actually on Windows this is due to the C runtime, not the shell. The double quotes affect how cmd parses the string for operators, but ultimately the command line is passed to python.exe exactly as its written, including the double quotes. It's then up to the C runtime to parse it as an `argv` array to pass to the `main` function. Notice that you're escaping with backslash, which is the escape character used by the CRT. cmd's escape character is a circumflex accent ("^").

Comment: I thought caret as a quote only applied to metachars like | and &?

Comment: It is the only escape character used by cmd. For example, try this `python -c "import os; print os.environ[\"&PATH\"]"`. As far as cmd.exe is concerned, the "&" character is outside of the quoted string, since it doesn't understand that backslash escaped the double quote. So "&" is parsed as the operator, and `PATH\"]"` is parsed as the 2nd command, which is the builtin `path` command, so now the current `%PATH%` is set to `\"]"`.

Comment: Thanks, this, alongside restarting the command prompt so that the environment variables were reloaded, led the problem to be fixed.

Comment: @jka.ne, note that the escaping option in this answer is a disaster waiting to happen. The backslash is not escaping the double quote in the eyes of the shell, cmd.exe, so special shell characters (e.g. &, <, >, |) between the two `\"` sequences will be parsed as operators by cmd.exe. It works in this case because the backslash escaping is required for the CRT *in the child process* that has nothing to do with the shell.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have used quotation marks inside quotation marks.

You can escape it or replace to semicolons.

```
$ python -c "import os; print os.environ['PATH']"
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think you are trying to pass Path as a list element to environ.But as environ is class which as you did in print os.environ.keys()is having member functions and not lists.
Hope this helps.